# error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, prestashop-1.6

I am configured PayPal sandbox account (test) mode in my prestashop 1.6
yesterday its working fine suddenly I got a error:

```
Error:
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
Connect failed with fsockopen method
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal updated its sandbox environment to only allow TLS 1.2 connections to improve security and prepare for future PCI compliance. You can find more information about the update on the [PayPal 2016 Merchant Security Roadmap Microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913&expand=true&locale=en_US).

If you use any of the PayPal SDKs, you can look at the [PayPal TLS Update](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update) repository for information on what SDKs or environment upgrades you may need. Please be aware there may be environment differences between running on the command line (say PHP CLI) vs. your application hosting environment (say the PHP module in Apache) so be sure you update all relevant environments.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same error. It's due to recent updates that PayPal have made: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766

You can fix it by adding this to your CURL options:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the followings in modules/paypal/api/paypal_connect.php

```
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, defined('CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1') ? CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 : 1);
```

as

```
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, defined('CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2') ? CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 : 6);
```

and it worked for me in both modes. Have a try :)